# Affine Transformation: Picking points

Tags: image, opencv, image-processing, affinetransform

I'm looking at OpenCV's tutorial on Geometric Transformations of Images, and under Affine Transformation, it states:

```
To find the transformation matrix, we need three points from input image and their corresponding locations in output image.
```

How will you know or determine their corresponding locations in the output image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you apply such a transformation, you want to find 3 points in the input image, and the exact same three points in the target image. [See an example here](http://blogs.mathworks.com/images/steve/2012/matched-features.jpg) with multiple points, but three are enough for an affine transformation. Then the registration is going to modify/twist the input image in order to register/align the triplets of points. So the triplet of points in input image is going to overlay the triplet of points in the target image.

The best algorithm I know for affine registration, including automatic interest point detection and matching, is the [TurboReg](http://bigwww.epfl.ch/thevenaz/turboreg/).

An other solution would be to use the SURF or SIFT algorithms to detect and match the points, then apply the affine transformation.